# Adding a field to searchable does not seem to have an effect - sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

```
ruby 2.1.5
rails 3.2.3
```

In my gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
```

In my ticket.rb, I added (to the searchable section):

```
  string :customer_reference
```

I uploaded the new ticket.rb to the staging server and did the following:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=staging  db:migrate
chmod -R -- g+w /home/app
RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
sudo reboot
echo \"DEPLOY SIDEKIQ RELOAD $(date)\" >> log/sidekiq.log
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -e staging
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
screen -d -m sh -c 'cd /home/app && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex'
```

When I did a search with a customer_reference, it did not find it. When I looked at the solr log file, I found the following:

```
INFO: [development] webapp=/solr path=/select params={fl=*+score&sort=requested_date_start_d+desc&start=0&q=139170&qf=services_text+inventories_text+requested_date_start_text+number_text+customer_phone_text+sp_name_text+specialties_text+status_text+ticket_type_text+executor_full_name_text+customer_full_name_text+customer_info_full_name_text+ticket_profile_name_text&wt=ruby&fq=type:Ticket&rows=20&defType=edismax} hits=1 status=0 QTime=27
```

customer_reference is not there. This is the first time I use solr, and I am trying to maintain this code. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Attempt1:

I rebooted my stating server and did the following:

```
RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
echo \"DEPLOY SIDEKIQ RELOAD $(date)\" >> log/sidekiq.log
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -e staging
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex[,,true]
```

I waited until it was done (the DB is not large). I did not see any errors in my terminal view. Still not working

Additional Comments:

I rebooted the server, so solr was not running. I did the following:

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

It started normally and gave me a PID

I then did:

```
rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

The process started and it was giving me an indicator telling me % done, time elapsed, etc and finished without any errors.

I was not asked to confirm if I wanted to reindex.

I am still not getting results

## Solution:

I struggled with this for a couple of days. I even deleted the solr and cache directories, re-generated the solr config and re-indexed, to no avail. The solution was very simple. I changed

```
string :customer_reference
```

to

```
text :customer_reference
```

and re-indexed. It worked fine. I am not sure why I cannot use string in the searachable section, but apparently I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way Solr indexes your database for searching into its own, separate database, any changes to the configuration will not be reflected in Solr until you [reindex](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#reindexing-objects) it with Sunspot:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex
```

Note that this may take a *very* long time depending on your data set size (some fulltext databases would take months to reindex completely), and that Solr will not have any records in its search while reindexing them all. You can mitigate these issues by reindexing in batches (explained further in link above):

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex[500,MyModel]
```

In that case, you would need to run the batched reindex `MyModel.count/500` times, but only 500 records at one time would be unavailable in Solr.

Comment: Oops. I forgot to include my deployment script. Please see my edits. I am re-indexing

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper That won't trigger the reindexing, because without the correct flag, sunspot reindex prompts you to type "yes" (after a warning about taking a long time like I mentioned above). Without the "yes", it never reindexes. Try running it "manually" to see what I mean. Moreover, its not a good idea to reindex every time you deploy for the same reasons. Regardless, if you want to automate, hopefully in a process separate from a usual deploy, per the same link above you need `bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex[,,true]`

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Do you see any output? The `rake sunspot:solr:start` should trigger an error if the solr process is already running. Try `ps aux | grep solr` to see if its running. Without the true flag, does `rake sunspot:reindex` prompt for `"yes"`? You can also try `MyModel.reindex` though IIRC that doesn't index new fields

Comment: Are you using latest-version sunspot and solr? I'm not sure what else to tell you, since you've done exactly what the sunspot docs suggest. I've only used solr via sunspot, but it looks like you're at the point where you may need to look into solr more directly to see what's wrong.

Comment: I deleted the entire solr directory, and started it from scratch. Still no sign of customer_reference in the sunspot log file. Note that if I enter a ticket number, for instance, it finds it (or ticket id).

Comment: Are you sure the new searchable code is on your server and being used by `rake`? Shooting in the dark here, but maybe this is a deploy or solr-unrelated issue since solr/sunspot seem to work fine...

Comment: It was looking for text :customer_reference instead of string :customer_reference, even though customer_reference is a string. Please see my edits